# R's read.csv() omitting rows

Tags: r, read.csv

In R, I'm trying to read in a basic CSV file of about 42,900 rows (confirmed by Unix's wc -l). The relevant code is

```
vecs <- read.csv("feature_vectors.txt", header=FALSE, nrows=50000)
```

where nrows is a slight overestimate because why not. However,

```
>> dim(vecs)
[1] 16853     5
```

indicating that the resultant data frame has on the order of 17,000 rows. Is this a memory issue? Each row consists of a ~30 character hash code, a ~30 character string, and 3 integers, so the total size of the file is only about 4MB.

If it's relevant, I should also note that a lot of the rows have missing fields.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looked to see whether the rows that *were* imported were imported correctly?

Comment: My guess is that you have embedded unmatched `"`.  So some of your rows are actually much longer than they should be.  I'd do something like `apply(vecs, 2, function(x), max(nchar(as.character(x)))` to check.

Comment: Yup! Justin got it. Adding `quote=""` fixed the problem.

Comment: @Justin, please put this as an answer so Cardano can accept it as the correct solution to his problem. :)

Comment: For the record, it's also the case that `read.table` can do some really screwy things if `fill=TRUE` and rows *after* the first five have more fields than any in the first five ... this is referred to obliquely in the help file ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of problem is often easy to resolve using `count.fields`, which tells you how many columns the resulting data frame would have if you called `read.csv`.

```
(n_fields <- count.fields("feature_vectors.txt"))
```

If not all the values of n_fields are the same, you have a problem.

```
if(any(diff(n_fields)))
{
  warning("There's a problem with the file")
}
```

In that case look at values of `n_fields` that are different to what you expect: the problems occur in these rows.

As Justin mentioned, a common problem is unmatched quotes.  Open you CSV file and find out how strings are quoted there.  Then call `read.csv`, specifying the `quote` argument.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you have embedded unmatched `"`. So some of your rows are actually much longer than they should be. I'd do something like `apply(vecs, 2, function(x), max(nchar(as.character(x)))` to check.